# Adding Ionic app to Rails 4 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ruby-on-rails-4, ionic3, api-design

I'm looking for advice.  I have a complex Rails 4 app that I need to add an Ionic 2/3 app on top of.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  What is the best way to add an API to an existing complex app?

Comment: Building endpoints for any feature you want to use. Let's say you have a module in your app that deals with orders, you just create an endpoint that returns a list of  all orders, then in your ionic app, you can just make a GET request to that endpoint.  Of course when you have to deal with things like authentication you'll have to build endpoints for same, I don't use ror but I'm pretty sure there are lots of packages for building out apis. What's really important is that you can then use the API with whatever frontend you want to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about ROR.But if you have a [**Rest API**](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html) then you can easily integrate it with `Ionic 3` app.The key thing here is you must have `Rest API`.After that, you can talk it through the Ionic `provider`.

> Ionic 3 front end app ---> Rest API ---> Backend Db